# JS access values

Tags: javascript, .net, model-view-controller

Using the following function

```
function firstFunction() {
            var url3 = "/Home/CheckPrintService?printer=" + document.getElementById("printerName").value;
            $.get(url3, null, function (data3) {
                $("#msgPrintService").html(data3);
                console.log($("#msgPrintService"));
            });
        }
```

I achieve to print data to the console:

[image]

I tried using `console.log($("#msgPrintService").get("innerText"));` to access the value highlighted in yellow. It does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
console.log($("#msgPrintService")[0].innerText);
```